# Apache Ignite Eviction Policy Max Size in Visor shown as <n/a>

Tags: ignite

My question is really simple.

I am using the example XML config for setting up the following Eviction Policy from https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions#section-first-in-first-out-fifo- .

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheConfiguration">
  <property name="name" value="myCache"/>

  <!-- Enabling on-heap caching for this distributed cache. -->
  <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>

  <property name="evictionPolicy">
    <!-- FIFO eviction policy. -->
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.fifo.FifoEvictionPolicy">
        <!-- Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000). -->
      <property name="maxSize" value="1000000"/>
    </bean>
  </property>

    ...
</bean>
```

How can I verify that my eviction policy has been setup successfully before start seeding data into my cache? I have been using `visor` and then the `config` command, I can see that `Eviction Policy Enabled` is set to `on`, `Eviction Policy` set to `o.a.i.cache.eviction.fifo.FifoEvictionPolicy` but `Eviction Policy Max Size` is set to `<n/a>` although it has been configured in the XML. That leads me to think that the Eviction policy max size is not setup correctly. Can someone share some light into this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs) has management beans, so you can verify your Cache configuration using MBeans. Just run a jconsole from JDK and check Cache configuration. Please see sample screenshot:
[image: Sample jconsole output]

Thanks, Alexey